# chartjs-2 pie chart how to remove lined tool-tip

Tags: react-chartjs-2

I want to remove this stupid lined tooltip or whatever this called
does any1 know how ?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

apparently you can control them by using plugin and style them as you like

```
   plugins: {
    outlabels:{
      text: (context) =>{
       return context
      }
      color: "#353948",
      backgroundColor: "#EFEFEF",
      borderColor: "#EFEFEF",
      lineColor: "#353948",
      lineWidth: 1,
      borderWidth: 0,
   }
  }
```